# how to remain the same data after changed or deleted the primary key (an instance)from model

Tags: python, django, model

i want to remain the same data as i saved before , after changing , or deleted the model which provide the foreign key ,

i tried to

```
on_delete=models.SET_NULL
```

but still removes the instance which i've saved before

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50 , 
    blank=False,null=False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product ,through='ProductOrder')
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()) 


    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.productorder_set.aggregate(
            price_sum=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'), 
            output_field=IntegerField()) )['price_sum'] 


class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL , null=True)
    ordering = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True ,default='')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product} : {self.quantity}"
```

and how save the total price in variable , if the the price in Product updated , it remains as the first time ?

and how to prevent losing data from Order model after removing a product from Product model thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but it generally has little to do with Django itself, because these are business decisions:

1. Don't link to the `Product` in the `Order` (and `ProductOrder`) models, but save the product information directly in the `ProductOrder` model. You could for example use a `JSONField` (if you're on PostgreSQL) and keep all the product details there, including the price.
2. Don't change a `Product` once it's been ordered once. i.e. you can make it impossible to change/delete a `Product` (`on_delete=models.PROTECT`). Give a `Product` a unique SKU and version number, create new versions of your `Product` when the price changes. That way all orders will use a reference to the `Product` that was actually ordered. When fetching `Products` that can be purchased, always fetch the latest version of the `Product`. You could create a new `ProductVersion` table for this and link to that instead of the `Product`.
3. Don't allow deleting a `Product` (`on_delete=PROTECT`), but allow changing the price. Note that if other characteristics of the `Product` change (such as color), you should always create a new `Product`. Keep a copy of the paid price in the `ProductOrder` itself (the line item of the order). This is the most common approach. You just copy the price in the line items, so that you always have actual price paid by the customer.

The solution you choose depends a bit on the business requirements of your company, i.e. how products are managed, what needs to be kept, etc... It also depends on what you want your customers to be able to see when looking up their historical orders.

Comment: thanks alot , but can you please explain a little more on third approach ! how to keep the price in the ProductOrder ? make a new field in ProductOrder named price ? i dont want to type the price every time .

Comment: Yes, add a `paid_price` field to `ProductOrder` and assign it when you also assign `quantity`. What do you mean “type” it? You just assign in the same place where you create the `ProductOrder` instance.

Comment: i mean i dont want to provide the price when i billing a form , i just want to get default price from product , i'll try to second option , (class ProductVersion(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
) i think this will solve my problem , thanks so much again , code field is something like barcode should be unique

Comment: But that’s not what I suggest in option 3. The price still comes from the product, you just *copy* it to the ProductOrder so that when later the price of the Prpduct changes, the paid price is still there on the order.

Comment: using save() method to provide default price ?

Comment: yup, you could do that on save() but be careful that it doesn't get changed later if it's saved again for some reason. so something like `if not self.paid_price: self.paid_price = self.product.price` will set it the first time, never again later.

Comment: you right , i much appreciate you , specially for second option idea